# How do I print numbers that exclude the column number: if column 2 print 1 3 4 5?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I want to use for loop to implement. Like,

```
col 1: 2 3 4 5 
col 2: 1 3 4 5 
col 3: 1 2 4 5 
col 4: 1 2 3 5 
col 5: 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is a good beginners' task. You'll learn best if you figure this out yourself rather than have us tell you how to do it.

Comment: "I want to use for loop to implement." Okay, so what goes wrong if you try to do that? What part of the problem is difficult for you? For example, are you able to determine the column number? Do you have a strategy in mind for excluding that column number from what you print? Can you write code that just prints the numbers, without worrying about that exclusion?

Answer (score 1):

write two loops,both of them starting from one and going up to 5.
In second loop check if the index of second loop is the same as first loop, if yes, don't print it out.

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int w;
    cin >> w;
    for (int i = 1; i < w+1; i++) {
        cout << "col " << i << "： ";
        for (int j = 1; j < w+1; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                cout << j<<" ";
            }
            
        }
        cout << endl;
    }   
}

Comment: congrats that's true.